# Does it make sense to declare all methods as static to save memory?

Tags: java

(When) does it make sense to declare methods `static` in this way? Will it save memory? How about the performance?

If I am right, `toString()` in the `Integer` wrapper class is working like this.

```
class Address {
  private static void method(Address adr) {
    // do something
  }

  public void method() {
    Address.method(this);
  }
}
```

```
class OtherClass {
  public static void main(String[] params) {
    Address a = new Address();
    a.method();
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it would save memory?

Comment: Never. No and I really doubt it. [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/2970947)

Comment: @kaya3 Because they exist only once, no matter how many objects I have. And I *asked* this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All instances of a class share the same code for each method. It doesn't matter whether the method is static or not - as long as the class is loaded at all, memory is being taken to define the contents of the method.

This isn't duplicated on a per-instance basis. Why should it be? All that changes between instances is *attributes*, not *behaviors*. Adding more instances will consume more memory, yes, but only for holding attributes - the behaviors still need only be defined once.

Comment: My understanding was that methods which are not static, will be copied in every instance of a class. So, in Java it is not true? But why the `toString()` method (e.g. in class `Integer`) is working like this?

Comment: They're not copied, no.  They don't have to be copied to be *run* separately on different objects, however.  The amount of memory consumed by a Java object has no relationship at all to what methods are defined on it, static or not.